# QGraphicsItem position after changing boundingRect

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have class derived from `QGraphicsItem`. It contains vector of points wich I draw in paint:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _vertexes.size(); i++)
{
     ...
  painter->drawEllipse(_vertexes[i], POINT_RADIUS, POINT_RADIUS);
}
```

when I add point in `_vertexes` with this code

```
 prepareGeometryChange();
 _vertexes.pop_back();
```

position of points in the view is changing, `boundingRect` is calculated using `_vertexes`

How to save points positions? I don't want all points change position after adding new one if new `boundingRect` is bigger. By the `pos()` returns always the same position (0, 0) but it could be in a different position of screen.

Comment: It sounds as if it's the `QGraphicsScene` being scrolled within the `QGraphicsView` when the bounding rect changes rather than the item actually changing position.  Try setting the scene rect [`explicitly`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop).

Comment: Thank you, setting of sceneRect helps me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't set initial sceneRect, so it was recalculated and scrolled after each increasing scene items bounding rect. Setting scene rect by `ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(x, y, width, heigh);` 
before adding of my items solves the problem,